# Does a conditional normal distribution imply an unconditional normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have often seen it claimed that for scalar random variables $y$ and $x$, the conditional normal distribution 
$$
  y\mid x\sim N(0,x^2)
$$ 
also implies the unconditional normal distribution 
$$
  y\sim N(0,x^2).
$$ 
Is this true? The result seems quite surprising, but maybe I'm just not appreciating it.

The explanations I have seen usually state that the conditional normal distribution implies 
$$
  x^{-1}(y\mid x)\sim N(0,1)
$$
(provided $x\neq 0$) in which the right-hand-side does not depend on $x$. Because the right-hand-side does not depend on $x$, we can drop the conditioning to obtain
$$ 
  x^{-1}y\sim N(0,1)
$$
and then rearrange to get
$$
  y\sim N(0,x^2).
$$
Is this argument logical? It seems a bit informal, although I haven't been able to contradict it.

The context is to conduct inference on a deterministic parameter $\mu$ when 
$$ 
  y\mid x\sim N(\mu, x^2)
$$
based on an observation of $(y,x)$. One could consider the interval 
$$ 
  (y- 1.96|x|, y+ 1.96|x|)
$$
which contains $\mu$ with 95% confidence conditional on $x$. Does this interval also contain $\mu$ with 95% confidence unconditional on $x$?

An example appears on page 35 of Hayashi, F. 2000. Econometrics:
[image]

Comment: "I have often seen it claimed that for scalar random variables $y$ and $x$, the conditional normal distribution 
$y|x\sim N(0,x^2)$ also implies the unconditional normal distribution $y\sim N(0,x^2).$" The first assertion is ok but the second is nonsense. What are your (numerous) sources? On the other hand, $x^{-1}y\sim N(0,1)$ is flawless provided $P(x=0)=0$.

Comment: I tried to provide more context for the question and will look for a reputable source (i.e. not lecture slides).

Comment: Even lecture slides (which can be quite *reputable*) available on the web and claiming this, would do.

Comment: An example appears on page 35 of Hayashi, F. 2000. Econometrics. Princeton University Press in the context of the classical linear regression model with conditionally normally distributed errors and known homoskedastic error variance. I'd like to refer you to the edit to my original question where I explain the context is inference about the parameter $\mu$. I take the point that $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ is non-sensical for $x$ random.

Comment: There is nothing of the sort on page 35 of Hayashi.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: Where do you see anything similar to $y\sim N(0,x^2)$" for some random $x$, in there?

Comment: I take the point that $y∼N(0,x^2)$ is non-sensical for x random. My question is about the interpretation of the interval $(y−1.96|x|,y+1.96|x|)$.

Comment: Ah, but this is quite unrelated to the text of your question (and well explained in the book, I must say). Unrelated: do we agree now that nowhere in the text is anything close to "$y\sim N(0,x^2)$" for some random $x$?

Comment: The text does not claim that $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ for $x$ random. Do you have any thoughts on whether $\mu\in (y-1.96|x|,y+1.96|x|)$ with probability 95% conditional and unconditional on $x$?

Comment: Yes, both hold. Note that $y=\mu+xz$ with $z$ standard normal independent of $x$ and that the event $A=[\mu\in(y-1.96|x|,y+1.96|x|)]$ of interest is $A=[|z|\lt1.96]$. This implies that $P(A)=95\%$ and $P(A|x)=95\%$ almost surely.

Comment: By specifying a distribution for $x$, I could imagine a scheme to simulate $y$ by first drawing an $x$ and then drawing a $y|x$. Wouldn't the existence of such a scheme imply that $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ could make sense for $x$ random?

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Couldn't we make sense of $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ for $x$ random by defining $y=xz$ with $z$ standard normal independent of $x$?

Comment: This is what $y\mid x\sim N(0,x^2)$ means, no? Say, after you claimed that "numerous" sources were using this absurd statement but you failed to provide a single one, where are you leading this question?

Comment: I think $y|x\sim N(0,x^2)$ means $y=xz$ with $x$ deterministic and $z$ standard normal, because $y|x\sim N(0,x^2)$ is just short-hand for $y|X=x\sim N(0,x^2)$ with $y,X$ random and $x$ deterministic. So $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ for $x$ random could make sense as $y=xz$ with $x,z$ random and $x$ independent of $z$.

Comment: No. Please check some textbook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you could have seen that claimed, but it doesn't make sense unless $x$ is a fixed constant.  If $x$ is a random variable, it's not clear what $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ would mean.

If $x$ is constant, then one can say that if $x^{-1}y\sim N(0,1)$ then $y\sim N(0,x^2)$.  It is also true that if the conditional distribution of one random variable given another does not depend on the other, then the marginal (or "unconditional") distribution of the first is the same as the conditional distribution.

But going from $x^{-1}y\sim N(0,1)$ to $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ is wrong unless $x$ is equal to some constant with probability $1$.

Comment: I tried to provide more context for the question and will look for a reputable source (i.e. not lecture slides).

Comment: You say you actually _observe_ the value of $x$.  Then you ask whether the distribution is $N(0,x^2)$ even if you don't observe $x$.  If you don't observe $x$, then what number appears in place of $x$ in the expression $N(0,x^2)$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I take your point that $y\sim N(0,x^2)$ is non-sensical for $x$ random. However, I think it's OK to ask whether the interval $(y−1.96|x|,y+1.96|x|)$ contains $\mu$ with 95% probability both conditional and unconditional on $x$. We have random variables $y$ and $x$ and we have one realisation of each of them.

Comment: If $\Pr(y-1.96|x|<\mu<y+1.96|x| \mid x)$ does not depend on $x$, then it is the same as the marginal (or "unconditional") probability $\Pr(y-1.96|x|<\mu<y+1.96|x|)$. ${}\qquad{}$